# What's the right method to display zoomable maps?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I want to build an app where I need to display a large map of a floor plan and be able to place yourself on the map.  I want to overlay an icon every time you want.

I have been looking at using the UIImageView with the appropriate pinch/zoom functions for the basic design, but is there a better method?

I would appreciate anyone's thoughts who may have done something similar.

Then I will do the research on the alternatives mentioned.

Thanks for your help.

Padapa

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`

```
UIImageView *tempImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
self.imageView = tempImage;

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width , imageView.frame.size.height);
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = .5;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
scrollView.zoomScale = .37;

-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)inScroll {
  return imageView; // <-- very important
}
```

Comment: Sha, thank you for your answer.  You ave shown me "how to", but I would like to know your "why to".  What made you selected this implementation.

Comment: this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html :)